# CORS works on plnkr, but not from browser: "The response had HTTP status code 403"

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, cors

Hi I've been working on an angularjs app on plnkr, and I'm pulling data from a remote server to the app. Initially I had problems accessing the xml file because of the CORS issue, the cross-domain restriction, but I enabled CORS. The app now works on plnkr, but when I try to run it on the browser, the console gives me the same error, except with an additional note at the end.

The error:

```
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://50.22.49.237:8084/XMLFiles/ReformatedSample.xml. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.`
```

The "the reponse had HTTP status code 403" bit seems to be new. What's going on? Why does it work on plnkr and not in browser? What do I need to do to fix it? Any help is appreciated.

Edit: The problem was with my browser - Google Chrome has a web security feature that doesn't allow me to open the app unless I disable it. I tested it in the disabled version of the browser and it works, but now I can't host these files on my website because the users won't be able to see the app if their web security is enabled. How do I work around this?

Comment: Is that your server at 50.22.49.237? Is it a nginx or apache server

Comment: A colleagues' server, and it is an apache server

Answer (score 0):

This is a security measure assured by your web browser, you can read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

you can work this around by adding this command to the .htaccess file in the service route directory:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Alternatively, you can add this to your HTTP response header.